# Is new physics a bad fit for Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, non-mainstream-physics

My interest is in new physics, from the point of view of propulsion, and experiments that can confirm or disprove related new hypotheses. New physics attracts people who want to casually speculate and not follow through with experiment.

New physics necessarily involves paradigm shifting thought which is difficult for anyone. Compounding the problem is that for all of the ideas propounded, the overwhelming majority of them will be invalid. A large number of ideas have to be considered and rejected for each good one that remains.

Is this a bad forum for generating conversation on questions of new physics? Is there a forum that may be a better fit for my interest? Or, if this is appropriate material for this site, what would be the best way to approach the topic here? Perhaps innocuous question with a link to chat?

Comment: the problem is the so-called demarcation problem between new physics and "nonmainstream" physics the latter of which is rejected on the site. however, the [chat] room is more open and there are lots of intermittent discussions about new physics there, but note that (speaking from long experience) its not really "anything goes" there either...

Comment: Well, for me new physics is writing an article in LaTex (no MS Word!!), and first passing through the no bull$hit filter at www.arxiv.org. Once your "new physics" article is there for everyone to see/read, you may come here to ask a well-formulated question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Technically, this site is not a forum; it's a Q&A site. It's not for generating conversation at all, it's for questions and answers to those questions. So based on that alone, this sounds like the wrong place for what you want to do.

You could bring up some of this stuff in [our chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71) (or create your own chat room), if other people are interested in discussing it with you. Besides that, I'd suggest looking outside of Stack Exchange for a more discussion-oriented site.

---

Setting aside that issue, if you wanted to ask a *question* about the sort of new physics you're talking about, it may be on topic or not, depending on the topic and the question. Generally, if you ask a question based on content that appears in published research papers in a reputable journal, it should be fine. Other than that, it's probably off topic, but the response you get could vary quite a bit depending on what exactly you're asking.

I would not advise posting questions on something like the EM drive unless the question is *clearly* based on content from a published paper in a highly reputable journal, with references and maybe even quotes included in the question. "Highly reputable journal" in this case means something like the APS's Physical Review series, or another of a similar caliber.